# Update error in trigger

Tags: sql, sql-server, triggers

I want to update some data column after inserting values. But it gives me some error. Please help me to fix this.

> Msg 4104, Level 16, State 1, Procedure TriggerBonus, Line 20
>   The multi-part identifier "i.User_id" could not be bound.

The trigger:

```
CREATE TRIGGER [dbo].[TriggerBonus] ON [dbo].[Bonus]
FOR INSERT
AS
DECLARE @rcnt int 
SELECT @rcnt = @@rowcount

IF(SELECT COUNT(*) FROM Bonus,inserted WHERE Bonus.Tpv = inserted.Tpv)!=@@rowcount

/* Cancel the insert and print a message.*/
      begin
      rollback transaction 
      end  

/* Otherwise, allow it. */
else

UPDATE Bonus
SET Subdealers_Id=('user')
WHERE (User_id = i.User_id)
```

Comment: As the error says, what is "i." in the last line? Did you intend "inserted."?

Comment: thanks for your reply.yes .i mean inserted.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your update needs to be :

```
UPDATE Bonus
SET Subdealers_Id=('user')
from inserted i inner join Bonus 
on {put your join here}
WHERE (User_id = i.User_id)
```

Comment: When posting code, highlight it and hit `{}`, or indent by four spaces - a lot easier than adding html markup yourself (and we get syntax highlighting)